# ls -ltr | grep "date | awk '{print $2" "$3}'" not working for single digit day

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

This is based on link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10041/how-to-get-only-files-created-after-a-date-with-ls/207251#207251

I found the below ls -ltr code to list the files of current date.

```
ls -ltr | grep "date | awk '{print $2" "$3}'"
```

Its providing output fine from 10th to 31st of the month. But its not providing output from 1st to 9th of the month. Then I found that there is an extra space month and day ie, the day is single digit not double.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall 11533 Jun 31 22:45 C_1025_2015JUN02.LOG.gz
```

: The above command worked fine.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle oinstall 11533 Jun  3 22:45 C_1025_2015JUN02.LOG.gz
```

: The above command didnt work as there extra space before 3 other than the single space month and day in linux (One decimal missing).

But this worked fine when I put one more single space between $2"  "$3 inside shell script. I would like have a permanent solution in the shell script. Is there anything extra I can add along with the above ls -ltr code for this space issue.

Comment: Follow the accepted answer in that question and see that parsing `ls` is not a good idea.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.

Comment: Infact my requirement is to fetch the total file size, count of files etc in a directory. Here below is the code I am using.

rtms_size=$(ls -ltr | grep "rtms" | grep ".rmbk" | grep "`date | awk '{print $2"  "$3}'`" | awk '{ total += $5 }; END { print total/1024/1024/1024 }')


rtms_cnt=$(ls -ltr | grep "rtms" | grep ".rmbk" | grep "`date | awk '{print $2"  "$3}'`" | awk '{print $9}' | wc -l)

The above is working fine except the at space issue because of single digit day.

Comment: Agreed, don't parse `ls`. But you want `grep "$(date "+%b %e")"`

Comment: @user3441224, why on earth didn't you put your requirements in your question? Check out the `stat` command.

Comment: Hey Glen

  I didnt think about converting the date.

grep "$(date "+%b %e")"

The above grep command worked fine.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Instead why dont you try the `find` command.

`find /data -mtime -1 |xargs |ls -l | awk '{print $2" "$3}'" | awk '{ total += $5 }; END { print total/1024/1024/1024 }'`

Comment: Infact my reqrment is to fetch the tot file size, cnt of files etc in a dir. Here below is the code I am using.

rtms_size=$(ls -ltr | grep "rtms" | grep ".rmbk" | grep "`date | awk '{print $2"  "$3}'`" | awk '{ total += $5 }; END { print total/1024/1024/1024 }')


rtms_cnt=$(ls -ltr | grep "rtms" | grep ".rmbk" | grep "`date | awk '{print $2"  "$3}'`" | awk '{print $9}' | wc -l)

The above works fine except the space issue becoz of single digit day.

If I have to use find command. Then how the syntax would be. Will I be able to use the search criteria same as above here also in find command.

Comment: Yet you can use find command, I have modified the answer check that